# Remove location from Firebase [GeoFire] - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, geofire

I have two screens, say A and B. On screen A, I store the user's current location on my Firebase database.

**Code**

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Fetching your location")

    backButton.isEnabled = false
    competitiveMatch.isEnabled = false
    friendlyMatch.isEnabled = false
    tournamentButton.isEnabled = false
    trainingButton.isEnabled = false
    nextButton.isEnabled = false

    let location = locations[locations.count - 1]

    if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        let userLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        let userLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude


        saveCurrentLocation(long: userLongitude, lat: userLatitude)

    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}
```

The function `saveCurrentLocation` is also declared in the same file as:

```
func saveCurrentLocation(long: Double, lat: Double){

    let geofireRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Locations")
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)

    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long), forKey: userID!) { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("An error occured: \(String(describing: error))")

            self.backButton.isEnabled = true
            self.competitiveMatch.isEnabled = true
            self.friendlyMatch.isEnabled = true
            self.tournamentButton.isEnabled = true
            self.trainingButton.isEnabled = true
            self.nextButton.isEnabled = true

        } else {
            print("Saved location successfully!")

            self.backButton.isEnabled = true
            self.competitiveMatch.isEnabled = true
            self.friendlyMatch.isEnabled = true
            self.tournamentButton.isEnabled = true
            self.trainingButton.isEnabled = true
            self.nextButton.isEnabled = true

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

On screen B, I have a logout button. I want to log out the user from the Firebase database and delete his saved location also when he presses on the button.

To do so, firstly I declare the following on top of the `ViewController` class:

```
let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
```

Then, I use the following code:

```
func deleteUserLocation(){

    let geofireRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Locations")
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)

    geoFire.removeKey(userID!)

    print("Deleted location.")
}

//Logout Button is pressed and it takes us back to the landing page.
@IBAction func logoutPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    deleteUserLocation()

    do {
        try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: There was a problem signing out!")
    }
}
```

Upon doing so, "Deleted Location" is printed in the console but the location isn't removed from the Database.

For reference, here is a snapshot of the database;

[image: Database]

Comment: Are you getting any errors? (My money is on a permission denied error)

Comment: No errors. "Deleted Location" is being printed to the console, but no errors.

Comment: I think you should add a completionlistener to see if you get any errors/succes.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Can you provide the exact code to do the same?

Comment: Utkarsh Sharma, can you please provide code of the GeoFire's removeKey method? It seems that the issue lives in that method.

Comment: I've written the same up there. Anyways, giving it again,

func deleteUserLocation(){

    let geofireRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Locations")
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)

    geoFire.removeKey(userID!)

    print("Deleted location.")
}

Comment: Only thing I can find is [this reverance](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geofireremovekey) (I have never used geofire myself)

Comment: @AndréKool Does Firebase provide the exact same uid every time a user logs in?

Comment: Each user has their own unique uid that (as far as I know) never changes.

Comment: I am very confused regarding this. Please forward my question to someone who might help.

Comment: Maybe this happening because I am using unwindSegue on the logout button?

Comment: Try logging your userID in the saveCurrentLocation and the deleteUserLocation and see if they match or try writing a hardcoded key to test the geofire.removeKey.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to remove de child in database.

```
    if geoFire!= nil {
        geoFire?.removeKey(userID!)
        geofireRef.child(userID!).removeValue()
        geoFire= nil
    }
```

OR

```
     geoFire?.firebaseRef.removeValue()
```